# How to create wifi batch qr code using excel sheet?

Tags: excel, qr-code, bulk

I am trying to create wifi batch qr-code using excel sheet.

The code I used is

```
=_xlfn.IMAGE("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&&cht=qr&chl="&A6)
```

where cell A6 `= WIFI:T:"WPA" S:"System" P:"12345678"`.

This function is not working, how can I solve it?

Comment: The formula should be : `=IMAGE("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl=WIFI:T:WPA;S:System;P:12345678;")` parameters are not following the pattern. and `_xlfn.` means the `IMAGE()` function doesn't supports your excel version. **[IMAGE()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/image-function-7e112975-5e52-4f2a-b9da-1d913d51f5d5)** applicable to `MS365` users

Comment: Thanks, so for excel version 2013 what should I do?

Comment: There is no alternatives for other versions for now, you may need to use `VBA` here.

Comment: I look at the vba code edit as you mentioned, working well now.

Comment: You can post your code as answers and accept the same so it helps others in the future

Answer (score 0):

WIFI:T:WPA;S:System;P:12345678; this format is correct.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).